# Why print function is showing error in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

[image]

Why the print statement is showing error in pycharm?

Comment: I think I might be using python 2, can you open a terminal and type `python --version` ?

Comment: @ValentinVIGNAL, that's perfectly valid Python 2. Nikita, I'd be very interested in what your *other* five errors were.

Comment: Please show error log here or 6 problems that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because you forgot to setup the python interpreter in pycharm settings,install latest python , set path to environment variable and set in pythcharm as default python interpreter.